# Why is this method of finding the area of a region with polar coordinates wrong?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the area A of the region enclosed by the spiral r=2 theta and the x-axis over the interval theta between 0 and pi inclusive. I tried the following:
$$A= \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{r=0}^{2\theta} dr d\theta$$

However this is wrong. Intuitively this integral makes sense to me so I’m confused why it’s not right.

Comment: In fact, you are missing the jacobian $\color{red}{r}$  : $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\left(\int_r \color{red}{r} dr\right) d\theta=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac12r^2d\theta$ https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/PolarArea.aspx

Comment: @JeanMarie I guess I’m confused why the jacobian is necessary

Comment: Consider the Jacobian as the "rectifying" multiplicative factor between two infinitesimal area element $dx dy$ (the "true" cartesian area) and the element of area $dr d\theta$ which is "distorted".